# Python Pipeline and its parameters

Tags: python

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()
from IPython.display import clear_output

!mkdir data
!wget http://dataincubator-wqu.s3.amazonaws.com/mldata/amazon_electronics_reviews_training.json.gz -nc -P ./data

import gzip
import json

with gzip.open("data/amazon_electronics_reviews_training.json.gz", "r") as f:                                  
    data = [json.loads(line) for line in f]
ratings = [review['overall'] for review in data]

from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator,TransformerMixin
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge
from spacy.lang.en import STOP_WORDS

class KeySelector (BaseEstimator,TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key
    
    def fit(self, X, y = None):
        return self 
    
    def transform(self, X):
        return [row[self.key] for row in X]

bag_of_words_model = Pipeline([
    ('selector', KeySelector('reviewText')),
    ('vectorizer', CountVectorizer()),
    ('regressor', Ridge())
])

bag_of_words_model.fit(data, ratings)
```

my result suppose to be like this

```
Pipeline(memory=None,
         steps=[('selector', KeySelector(key='reviewText')),
                ('vectorizer',
                 CountVectorizer(analyzer='word', binary=False,
                                 decode_error='strict',
                                 dtype=<class 'numpy.int64'>, encoding='utf-8',
                                 input='content', lowercase=True, max_df=1.0,
                                 max_features=None, min_df=1,
                                 ngram_range=(1, 1), preprocessor=None,
                                 stop_words=None, strip_accents=None,
                                 token_pattern='(?u)\\b\\w\\w+\\b',
                                 tokenizer=None, vocabulary=None)),
                ('regressor',
                 Ridge(alpha=1.0, copy_X=True, fit_intercept=True,
                       max_iter=None, normalize=False, random_state=None,
                       solver='auto', tol=0.001))],
         verbose=False)
```

but unfortunately my result look like this

```
Pipeline(steps=[('selector', KeySelector(key='reviewText')),
                ('vectorizer', CountVectorizer()), ('regressor', Ridge())])
```

I try to key in the parameters manually, but still get the empty pipeline above.
My result is so poor under this pipeline. What had i missed?
What should i do? Thank you.